# OpenSansSemiBold seems unavailable on localhost

Tags: css, fonts, stylus, font-family

I've recently been overhauling my frontend code to use Stylus instead of CSS. Mostly it's gone okay but now wherever I use the font `OpenSansSemiBold` it just looks like the browser's default font. Even when I manually add the `font-family: 'OpenSansSemiBold'` attribute in Chrome developer tools it doesn't change to the correct font, whereas doing that works on my currently-deployed live version of the site. Any idea what might be preventing this font from being found?

EDIT: I'm using nginx on local (same as on live). Google's fonts are imported just above where the preprocessed CSS is imported like so:

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,600,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: On your live site are you linking to google fonts? are you testing your local website offline? how are you adding that font to the page?

Comment: If you're testing this in HTML without a server, make sure you're using ``http://fonts.googleapis.com`` instead of `//fonts.googleapis.com`. Might help to show your code too...

Comment: Thanks for the questions, I've updated my question with the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Google Fonts you should be using `font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;` when defining your font.

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,600,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
</style>

<!-- define as bold -->
<strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, </strong>
```